# Customize Menu - All Addresses

Tags: menu

I would like to insert a new point in the menu "All addresses". How can I show all addresses without going through the search function.
Wordpress 5.3 CiviCRM 5.19 - Thanks Felix

Comment: Can you add more details? Do you mean you want to only display all addresses from the database on this menu path?

Comment: as in the search without criteria (*)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is create a Constituent report through here - /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Fcontact%2Fsummary&reset=1

You can add in the fields you'd like the report to show (so address fields in your case).

Once you've created the report, you can copy and paste the report URL and add it to the menu here - /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fmenu&reset=1

Comment: that did not work for me

Comment: I would like to have the result as in the search without criteria